# Undefined reference to ipv6_dev_find when compiling with allmodconfig, not present when compiling with allyesconfig

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to modify the icmp_echo function in `net/ipv4/icmp.c` while running the Linux net-next branch on Ubuntu. I've tested and compiled the file numerous times using a .config generated from my locally installed kernel, and have had no problems. I've also tested compilation with allyesconfig and had no errors. However, when testing compilation with make allmodconfig, I get the error:

```
ld: net/ipv4/icmp.o: in function `icmp_echo':
icmp.c:(.text+0x2613): undefined reference to `ipv6_dev_find'
make: *** [Makefile:1177: vmlinux] Error 1
```

I understand that allmodconfig compiles many more modules than allyesconfig and my local .config, but why is it unable to find this function? It has no issues finding `ip_dev_find()` or any other function I'm using. I am including `<net/addrconf.h>`, the file that defines `ipv6_dev_find()`, so shouldn't that be enough to allow the compiler to find the function? What is it about allmodconfig that causes this behavior?

I've looked into things like calling `extern net_device *ipv6_dev_find(struct net*, const struct in6_addr*, struct net_device*)` at the top of the file as one method of explicitly calling the `ipv6_dev_find` function, but I haven't been able to find any example in the kernel that uses this approach, so I feel like this is heading in the wrong direction.